# Error to install gnutls

Tags: software-installation

I’m trying to install `gnutls` but get an error message:

```
$ sudo apt install gnutls
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnutls
```

I take us.ubuntu as source in software update setting.

How to install `gnutls` properly?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `sudo apt search gnutls` or [visit packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gnutls) before trying to install it.

I guess what you want to install is:

```
sudo apt install gnutls-bin
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: it does not return helpful info `[sudo] password for me: 
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
`